# Pasar de ValueEventListener a ChildEventListener

Tags: android-studio, firebase, recyclerview, app, paginación

Buen día a todos, quien pueda ayudarme lo agradecería mucho.
**Estoy llenando un recyclerView desde firebaseRealtime** pero cuando se modifica un snapshot todo el método se vuelve a lanzar y carga nuevamente toda la lista, y esto no es correcto para el usuario.

Deseo que solo el snapshot modificado y no todos los eventos.

Les paso mi código:

---

posteoProductsList = new ArrayList<>();

```
    //trayendo los datos del db
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //clear list
            posteoProductsList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                String uid = ""+ds.getRef().getKey();  //trayendo todos los uid de los sellers y users

                final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Posteos");
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()){
                            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                                ModelPosteo_products modelPosteo_products = ds.getValue(ModelPosteo_products.class);
                                //add to list
                                posteoProductsList.add(modelPosteo_products);
                            }
                            //setup adapter
                            adapterShowAllPosteos = new PruebaPosteosAdapter(PruebaPosteosActivity.this, posteoProductsList);
                            //set adapter to recyclerView
                            posteosRv.setAdapter(adapterShowAllPosteos);
                            adapterShowAllPosteos.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que deberias cambiar es que en vez de usar `addValueEventListener` lo cambies por `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` ya que el primero va a estar escuchando todo el tiempo pero el segundo solo se va a disparar una sola vez, jugando con el tipo de listener que atachas a la request vas a evitar que siempre reacciones a un cambio en la base de datos tu listener.

Comment: Hola, recien leo tu mensaje, me llamo Jhon y soy de Peru, tu crees que me puedas ayudar con algunos puntos de mi App? .. es que busco y busco informacion y no l encuentro y me siento estancado sin poder avanzar en la App.. tu me dices cuando me cobrarias y procedemos..

Espero tu respuesta por favor, mi whatsapp es: +51997962750